# Firefox Developer Edition web console does not have sidebar anymore

Tags: firefox, console, firefox-developer-edition, web-console

I have been using Firefox for a while now and switched to the developer edition recently. What I found was that the Web Console now displays variables as drop down options and not in a sidebar like previous versions. [image]

Am I missing an extension or something or is this how the Web Console behaves now?

Comment: I think you miss nothing... i  try to search javascript in all code, as was possible in normal firefox, but you  cant... I don't understand why they call it developer edition...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Am I missing an extension or something or is this how the Web Console behaves now?

Yes, this was an intentional change.

Comment: Also maybe worth noting that there's a bug to allow the side panel again as well: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1380501